# HTML href url error when using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in my root directory. It's this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In my index.php file I tried to do the following :

```
<img src="myimage.png"/>
```

The image wasn't loaded, however. When I delete the .htaccess file and refresh the page the image comes back.

So what's the problem here ??

Comment: What is the URL you tried?

Comment: Your problem is that `myimage.png` is matched by `^(.+)` and thus the rule is applied.

Comment: Is your index.php file serving the image file when requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is also matched by the expression so its also redirected to index.php. You could try to exclude images by using a rewrite condition for extention.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦css¦js¦doc¦mp3¦pdf¦xls)$
```

Another option is to use a condition that excludes files that exist

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

And directories that exists

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thanks, and that worked fine as I expected. But there's a one more problem. Directory of my website is "localhost/site/", if i go to "local/site" using my browser, no problem. But if i try "localhost/site/a/", then it won't work.